# What could be limiting me from adjusting my monitor's resolution to its highest setting in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors

I'm currently running Windows XP on a machine with dual monitors.  Until recently, those two monitors were identical 24" Dells with native resolutions of 1920x1200.  I just replaced one of the 24" monitors with a 30" Dell monitor that has a native resolution of 2560x1600.  As soon as I hooked it up, I was able to set the resolution to its native res of 2560x1600.  After I rebooted once, the resolution got changed by the system and highest it will go is 1920x1440, which looks horrible.  My question is, why can't I set it higher to its original native resolution of 2560x1600?

A few other things worth mentioning...I'm running two dual monitor programs called DisplayFusion and MultiMon Toolbar, both of which I suspect could be messing with things.  However, I've turned off both and restarted and the problem still persists.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you installed drivers for the new monitor?  sounds like XP isn't detecting it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a limitation of the video card.  More specifically, it might be the case that your video card can only handle either two single-link DVI displays or one dual-link DVI display.  More info on the DVI spec here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#Specifications

Try removing the second monitor and see if that lets you use the full native resolution of your new monitor.  If removing the second monitor allows you to use the new monitor at its native resolution, you can install a second video card in order to use the second monitor (and, naturally, you'll probably experiment with re-adding your other 24" monitor for a triple gigantor display).

I had to install a separate video card in one of my computers because the onboard video chipset could only handle one monitor at 1280x1024, and when I added a second monitor it bumped the resolution of both down to 1024x768.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to change the resolution with the applet from the maker of your video card, or with the Windows desktop properties?

I find that you generally have to use the program from the video card manufacturer first.

Answer (score 0):

go to **Settings** in the **Display Properties** > **Advanced** > **Monitor** and clear the box **Hide modes that this monitor cannot display** and apply.

now check if 2560x1600 is available.